# Unable to find explicit activity class in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an android project with several packages. The structure of the packages in this case is com.siva.restorative is the package that contains the activity I want to run.

My activities are declared in my manifest as

```
 <activity android:theme="@style/YtdTheme" android:name="com.siva.restorativecare.RestorativeCare">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The mainScreen activity displays fine, since it is inside the com.WAPP package. But when I try to run the setLocationActivity, I get the unable to find explicit class error. Here is how I have the intent parameters:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
```

Comment: **SecondActivity.class** how is it declared in manifest...? post that too..

Answer (score 0):

I guess first you should change the action string in manifest as:

```
<action android:name="com.siva.restorativecare.RestorativeCare" />
```

and then start running your activity as:

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.siva.restorativecare.RestorativeCare");
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thanks, for the reply. but its not working same error occurring.

Comment: are you sure `android:name="com.siva.restorativecare.RestorativeCare"` is defined correctly for your activity?

Comment: yes, com.siva.restorativecare its my package and RestorativeCare this is class name.

Comment: paste your class files and manifest... there must be something wrong in the references